# counting not printing prime numbers

Tags: r, function

```
is.prime <- function(x) {
  if(x == 1) return(FALSE)
  else return(!any(x %% seq(1, floor(x - 1))[-1] == 0))
}
```

Could you please modify or add extra code counting 168 prime numbers less than 1000. COUNTING NOT PRINTING. Should be just a short sentence

Comment: for (x in 1:1000) {
  if(is.prime(x))
    print(x)
} #this can print out prime numbers between 1 to 1000 but i'm not sure how to just count prime numbers

Comment: sum(sapply(1:1000, is.prime))